# PHPexcel Comma Style

Tags: php, excel

Im using PHPexcel Library for exporting data in my SQL Server Database

Is there a way to style a cell with `"Comma Style"`, e.g., `"1000000" as "1,000,000"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the [number format](http://php.net/number_format) function

```
<?php
    echo number_format(1000000);//will output 1,000,000
```

Do read the full docs though, number_format() is far more powerful than that.